# Android support library v4 dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-support-library

What I am trying to do ?
I have got this fragment which loads up an xml. within that xml I have an image button and it should display a dialog message.

This is the code for the fragment ;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class LoadingupFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.example, container, false);

 return v;
}


public void dialogboxalert (View view){

    ExampleAlert dialog = new ExampleAlert();
   // dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),""); ERRRORRR

}
```

This is the code for the dialog ;

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ExampleAlert extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("This is my dialog..").setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        }).setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Please can someone help me with the support library issue ??

Comment: Perhaps your ExampleAlert dialog extends for android.app.DialogFragement. it should exends ansdorid.support.v4.app.DialogFragment

Comment: this is the line which gives me the error "                                                                 // dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),""); ERRRORRR".. error is "Cannot resolve method 'show (android .support.v4.app.FragmentManager.java.lang.String)'"

Comment: add imports for ExampleAlert class

Comment: Okay I have made the changes you told me to do. new post is with all the changes you asked me to do

Comment: and now it should works

Comment: but i still can't use the getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72136/discussion-between-konrad-krakowiak-and-user3511639).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue occurs because your DialogFragment extends  `android.app.DialogFragement` and it should extends `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`

Answer (score 3):

Since Google released new support library, you should extend your dialog fragment using this class AppCompatDialog

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialog.html